# Laravel queryBuilder (5.6)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Hello I'm trying to replicate this SQL code into Laravel qBuilder but I'm not getting the result I want in the collection:

```
select chars.name, class.name, specs.name
FROM characters as chars 
JOIN charclasses as class
JOIN charspecs as specs
WHERE chars.class_id = class.id
AND chars.spec_id = specs.id
```

I get the following output:
[image]

Then I tried this in Laravel:

```
$charData = DB::table('characters')
        ->select('characters.*', 'charclasses.name', 'charspecs.name')
        ->join('charclasses', 'characters.class_id', '=', 'charclasses.id')
        ->join('charspecs', 'characters.spec_id', '=', 'charspecs.id')
        ->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')
        ->get();
    dd($charData);
```

and the result is:
[image]

Comment: I bet you can use Eloquent and correct use of relationships, take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships). Good Luck!

Comment: I'm learning by developing something gaming related to be more motivated, haven't got to the Eloquent/relationship part yet, but I will do in the next days, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are selecting three fields with the same name. These fields are added to an array in the php code, but the array field is being overwritten twice because there can be no duplicate keys in an associative array. If you want to select the three names you will have to give them another name.

```
$charData = DB::table('characters')
    ->select('characters.*', 'charclasses.name as charclassname', 'charspecs.name as charspecname')
    ->join('charclasses', 'characters.class_id', '=', 'charclasses.id')
    ->join('charspecs', 'characters.spec_id', '=', 'charspecs.id')
    ->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')
    ->get();
dd($charData);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, I thought that was automated like SQL, I changed like you suggested and worked like a charm

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the solution so other users might also find it.